# Previously working program suddenly starts with just title bar visible

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe8

I have a program I wrote in Delphi XE8, which previously worked properly, but which now starts with little more than the title bar visible.
To be precise, for a split second the full form is visible, but then it collapses to a height of 37 pixels; not even enough to fully display the menu bar.

I couldn't remember that this version of the program had any recent changes, but I checked previous versions of the program, and they all behave the same erroneous way. I copied the .exe file to another computer and there the program still works fine.

I tried to find any bug in the code by selectively commenting out modules. In the end there was NOT A SINGLE line of code in the source anymore, but still the same problem. 
Then I replaced the main (and only) form, where I removed any code, by a new and empty form. This way any wrong parameters with on form components would be put aside. The problem STILL was there! So I figured it had to be the project file. Compared byte by byte with another, working project source file: no differences whatsoever. Even when I replaced the code from the erroneous project file with that of the OK project file (copy-paste) the error persisted.

Creating a completely new VCL application: no problems whatsoever. Neither with other projects. I seriously ran completely out of ideas now (which may be a clue that it's something rather banal).

Anyone with similar experiences? AND preferably a solution? If you need more information, shoot! 
Did I say that the behavior started with a .exe file which worked properly earlier on, and that it still works on another PC?

TIA
Steven

---

**Edit**
Both PCs mentioned have the same Windows 10 version:

> Home Edition,
>   Version 1903,
>   Build 18362.535

Comment: Impossible to say what's happening on your machine. But I would blame aliens :) Besides I'd suggest using versioning system.

Comment: If its not code, it still could be the dfm

Comment: @TLama - Yeah, I guess you're right about the versioning system (not so much about the aliens, IMO). OTOH, I'm not sure how a versioning system could help: there were NO CHANGES between the program which worked last Friday, and the program I'm running now. NONE. We're talking about the same .exe file. And yes, the same .exe file which worked correctly on the other PC.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - I explained that I tried to cover that by replacing the form by a completely new one, that is: a new .pas file + new .dfm file.

Comment: and what about the dpr?

Comment: Does changing the executable name help?

Comment: @whosrdaddy - Thanks for thinking along. The .dpr contains the project's source, which you can open in your editor from the Project menu -> View source. I said I had compared against a well-behaving source, and even replaced the erroneous code by the other one (copy all -> paste). Also, like I said in my other comment and my OP: the .exe started to behave strangely without any of the source been modified.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - Goddammit Sertac! How did you do that!? It does work again when i rename it. Thanks a bunch! You may change your comment into an answer, but TBH, I have no any WHY this works, i.e. what a program's name has to do with form height. And also, it's not the proper way to fix things; I should be able to choose any filename I want to, shouldn't I? But thanks again.

Comment: @MartynA - I removed the first form ("form1.* ") from the project, and added a new one ("form2.* "). Form1 was removed from the .dpr uses clause, so I don't think it was necessary to actually delete the .dcu. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: @steve - Most probably it's a shim, DPI or similar. Event log, Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft Windows Application-Experience Program\Telemetry to confirm. Search in registry to find and remove it.

Comment: Windows may have saved a very small size for your application. Try setting the MinWidth and Minheight Constraints on the form.

Comment: If you can't remove the shim, an alternative to changing the name is to change the major version of the executable.

Comment: @Brian - Windows does not save application's windows.

Comment: Did you manually changed  something in the Compatibility properties page of your exe file? @SertacAkyuz, nice catch! :)